# JMeter jp@gc-WebDriver Sampler — Run the Webpage from MS Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have the Webpage that need to perform the multi test cases for automation test and currently need to hard code the text variables from WebDriver Sampler by Groovy. And I would like to know that JMETER WebDriver can pickup the data from MS. Excel and performing the test? Like says the I need key in the login page and select the items from dropdown box from the webpage. The next step will be confirm the order by input the Credit Cards information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to [convert MS Excel file into CSV file](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/save-a-workbook-to-text-format-txt-or-csv-3e9a9d6c-70da-4255-aa28-fcacf1f081e6), if you're able to do it - you can read the values using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)

If the file is coming from external location and it's in one of binary formats (.xls or .xlsx) - it's still can be done, but you will have to do some scripting like:

1. Download [tika-app.jar](https://tika.apache.org/download.html) to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. Restart JMeter to pick the .jar up
3. Use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) library for reading data from Excel. The code will be different for different file formats and your Excel structure so I can only provide a couple of links with examples and snippets:

   - [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html)
   - [How to Implement Data Driven Testing in your JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-implement-data-driven-testing-in-your-jmeter-test)

Comment: Thanks for advise. BTW I need to  created the login and some transaction from the Website. Can you please provide some sample coding? Some like reading the CSV file and perform to the Webpage.